# Wix toolset not creating Uninstall in Add Remove Programs

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix 4 Install script, and when I install the application, with the Installer, using a `Bundle`, the Uninstall entry is not in Windows Control Panel Uninstall

> `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features`.

However when I install the `MyApp.msi` without the `Bundle` the Uninstall entry is made.

What could be the cause?

Here is the **Bundle**

```
   <Wix
   xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
   xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

   <Bundle Name="MyAppBundle" 
       Version="1.0.0.0" 
       Manufacturer="MyApp" 
       UpgradeCode="a Guid"
       >

   <BootstrapperApplication>
        <bal:WixInternalUIBootstrapperApplication />
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <!-- Arch variables -->
    <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
        <?define arch = "x64" ?>
    <?endif ?>

    <!-- always x86 here, in Msi Project use blank -->
    <?if $(var.Platform) = x86 ?>
        <?define arch = "x86" ?> 
    <?endif ?>

    <?if $(var.Platform) = ARM64 ?>
        <?define arch = "arm64" ?>
    <?endif ?>

    <Chain>
        <!-- Install VC++ Redistributable -->
        <PackageGroupRef Id="VCRedist" />
        <!-- Install Main Application -->
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="../MyApp/bin/$(arch)/Release/en-US/MyApp.msi"/>
    </Chain>

</Bundle>

<Fragment>
    <!-- Reference the VC++ Redistributable PackageGroup -->
    <PackageGroup Id="VCRedist">
        <ExePackage Id="VCRedistExe"
                    DisplayName="Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable"
                    SourceFile="../vc-redist/VC_redist.$(arch).exe"
                    InstallArguments="/quiet /norestart"
                    DetectCondition="VCRedistInstalled"
                    Permanent="yes"
                    Vital="yes">
            
                    <!-- Restart Required -->
                    <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot"/>

                    <!-- Ignore "Newer version installed" error -->
                    <ExitCode Value="1638" Behavior="success"/>
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Look at the log file created by the Bundle. Something is probably going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @RobMensching, there was a warning about the perMachine / perUser on my Burn project. After altering the MsiPackage (referenced from the Burn Project) to be "perMachine" instead of "perUserOrMachine"; I get to see the "Uninstall entry";

But something else is up. When I Uninstall, the "Redistrabutable" want's to install again; and "Accepting it", the Redistributable Installs "again", and the MsiPackage does not uninstall.

Comment: There is no entry in Programs and Features, but your application is installed or not ?

Comment: Initially there was no entry; then at some point I had an entry, but would not uninstall. then following that I has duplicate entries; and then finally It all worked, by trying various combination of properties: what worked was as my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After making these changes the Install worked for me (but could contain mistakes):

The `Bundle MsiPackage`

```
<MsiPackage 
     Visible="yes" 
     DisplayName="MyApp" 
     Vital="yes" 
     Id="MyApp" 
     SourceFile="../MyAppInstaller/bin/$(arch)/Release/en-US/MyAppInstaller.msi"/>
```

Also added this to the `Bundle ExePackage`:

```
     Permanent="true"
     UninstallArguments="/s /uninstall"
     bal:PrereqPackage="true"
```

And my `MSI Package Project` has this (outputs `MyAppInstaller.msi`):

```
    <Package
    Name="MyApp"
    Manufacturer="Me"
    Version="1.0.0.0"
    UpgradeCode="The GUID"

    Scope="perUserOrMachine" // << try with perMachine
  >
```